# Dependency Injection By Autofact For Specflow

Tags: .net, specflow

I Want To Implement DI For Specflow, Therefor I Installed Specflow.Autofac After Successfull Installation And Run Of Specflow It Self. Just After Installation Of Specflow.Autofac Everything Goes Wrong And I Get This Error For Running Or Debugging Test :

```
Could not load type TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.IBindingInstanceResolver
```

I Didn't Get Proper Result Of My Searches Arround This Problem. I Appreciate For Any Help In This Problem Or Step By Step Procedure For Implementation Of Dependency Injection For Specflow

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Tried To Implement DI For Specflow By It's Own IoC Container. Specflow Has a Built-In IoC Container Called ObjectContainer. It Can Be Implemented Like This To Enable DI For Specflow:

```
[Binding]
public class TestDependecies
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void SetupContainer()
    {
        var objectContainer = (IObjectContainer)ScenarioContext.Current.GetBindingInstance(typeof(BoDi.IObjectContainer));

        var wiringContainer = new WiringContainerWrapper(objectContainer);

        TestConfigurator.Configure(wiringContainer);
    }
}
```

After Evaluating On Container Setup By Hooking To `BeforScenario` Attributes, Injection Can Be Achived By Constructor Injection For Step Classes.

```
[Binding]
public class PromotionsSteps
{
    private readonly IItemFacade itemFacade;
    private readonly IPromotionFacade promotionFacade;

    public PromotionsSteps(IItemFacade itemFacade,
        IPromotionFacade promotionFacade)
    {
        this.itemFacade = itemFacade;
        this.promotionFacade = promotionFacade;
    }

    [Given(@"I have a stepBase with name '(.*)' promotion with following values :")]
    public void GivenIHaveAStepBaseWithNamePromotionWithFollowingValues(string p0, Table table)
    {
        ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: If you have solved your own problem please "Accept" this answer, otherwise please include this code in your question.
As an aside, you only need to capitalise the start of sentences, no offense ;).

Comment: @codemonkeh thanks for your attention but i cant accept my answer in 23 hours

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to update SpecFlow.Autofac to a version that supports your used SpecFlow version. SpecFlow.Autofac is not released by the SpecFlow team.

In most minor releases we are changing the plugin interface and so plugins has to update. The current stable package of SpecFlow.Autofac says it support SpecFlow >= 2.1. This is wrong, because we changed the inferface with 2.2.
You could try to install the latest pre-release version (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.Autofac/1.1.0-pre20171024) which says it supports SpecFlow >= 2.2.1, but I am not sure if we changed the plugin interface with 2.3.

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there any decide to empower objectContainer to support dependency injection registration by conventions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with registration by conventions. But open an issue on GitHub and we can discuss it there.